# Remove extra characters from diff output

Tags: regular-expression

I have the below output from unix:

```
$ diff -y --suppress-common-lines backup.txt newfile.txt
                                                              > `jjj' int,
```

i need only `jjj : int` as output. tried the below didn't work as expected:

```
$ diff -y --suppress-common-lines backup.txt newfile.txt | grep -i '>' |tr -d '[>]'  |sed 's/,//g'
```

[image]

Comment: To get `jjj : int`, you just need `echo 'jjj : int'`. Assuming the input will not always be `` `jjj' int, ``, you'd need to tell the rules by which you get from that input to the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You could tell `diff` to give you just that with:

```
diff --old-line-format= \
     --unchanged-line-format= \
     --new-line-format=%L backup.txt newfile.txt
```

To post-process the `diff -y` output, you could do:

```
diff  -y --suppress-common-lines backup.txt newfile.txt |
  LC_ALL=C sed -n $'s/^[[:blank:]]*>\t//p'
```

But that's not foolproof if `backup.txt` may contain lines like `[blanks]>[TAB][anything]` for instance.

`$'...'` is a special type of quote from ksh93 (now also supported by a few other shells), where `\t` is expanded to a TAB character. It's not needed with the GNU implementation of `sed`, where `\t` matches a TAB already (though not insider bracket expressions).

In the `C` locale, `[[:blank:]]` matches on either space or tab.

Pipe those to

```
tr -d \`\',
```

to remove the `` ` ``, `'` and `,` characters from their output.

And to:

```
sed 's/[[:space:]]\{1,\}/ : /g'
```

To replace sequences of one or more whitespace characters on each line with `" : "`.

Or combining the two into one `sed` command:

```
sed 's/[`,'\'']//g; s/[[:space:]]\{1,\}/ : /g'
```

Or combined with the `sed` command that post-processes the side-by-side output:

```
sed $'s/^[ \t]*>\t/!d
      s///p
      s/[`,'\'']//g
      s/[[:space:]]\{1,\}/ : /g'
```

Comment: can you help remove `  & , from output and include : between two words?
o/p for your command:
`jjj' int,

Comment: @rose, see edit.

Comment: $  diff -y --suppress-common-lines backup.txt newfile.txt| sed 's/[`,'\'']//g; s/[[:space:]]\{1,\}/:/ : /g'
sed: -e expression #1, char 36: unknown option to `s'

Comment: @rose, sorry, typo my bad. See edit.

Comment: diff -y --suppress-common-lines backup.txt newfile.txt | sed 's/[`,'\'']//g; s/[[:space:]]\{1,\}/ : /g'
 : > : jjj : int

Comment: @rose, you forgot the stripping of the `blanks>tab`

Answer (score 0):

Something like in `awk` can do the work:

```
diff -y --suppress-common-lines backup.txt newfile.txt|awk -F'[>,]' '{gsub(/ /,"")} {print $2} '
```

Comment: `jjj' int
i still get spaces in front

Comment: @rose, edited, something like can do the work

Comment: @rose then please edit your question and add i) ann example input we can use to reproduce your output ii) the output you want and iii) an explanation of what should be removed. Do you want to remove all `'` and `\``? All non-alphanumeric characters? Something else?